# Spring Boot with Embedded Mongo : Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I am trying to setup a JUnit test for a Spring Boot with embedded Mongo & Kafka :-

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE,
        classes = {AccountingApplication.class})
@DataMongoTest
public class BaseEmbeddedTest {


    @ClassRule
    public static KafkaEmbedded embeddedKafka = new KafkaEmbedded(1, true);

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;


    @Test
    public void emptyTest(){

    }

}
```

> src/test/resources/application.yml :-

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      port: 0
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: ${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers}
```

**PROBLEM**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.config.IMongodConfig]: Factory method 'embeddedMongoConfiguration' threw exception; nested exception is java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 140 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:106)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:190)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.runtime.Network.getFreeServerPort(Network.java:80)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.embeddedMongoConfiguration(EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.java:147)
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Version:-

```
    dependencyManagementPluginVersion = '1.0.3.RELEASE'
    springBootVersion = '1.5.6.RELEASE'
    springCloudVersion = 'Dalston.SR2'
    projectVersion = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    javaVersion = 1.8
    kotlinVersion = '1.1.4'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This annotation: `@DataMongoTest` causes Spring Boot to create an embedded Mongo instance. The exception messages tells us that the embedded Mongo instance cannot start because there is already a process running on the port it is trying to run on.

The embedded Mongo instance is configured by `EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration` and the strategy applied by Spring Boot - for port allocation - is as follows:

```
if configured Mongo port > 0 then 
    use the configured port
else 
    assign a random port
end
```

So, I suspect that your test context is configured with a non zero value for `spring.data.mongodb.port`. I know you posted your application.yml which implies that you are - correctly - assigning a zero value to `spring.data.mongodb.port` but if you put a breakpoint inside the `EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration` constructor and peek inside the properties parameter I think you'll see that the actual value in use by that configuration class is not zero. If the port value passed to `EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration` is actually zero but you are still getting the JVM_Bind error then that implies that this call: `Network.getFreeServerPort(this.getHost())` is not returning a free port  and that seems unlikely.

In order to fix this issue: as long as you configure your test context with `spring.data.mongodb.port=0` then the embedded Mongo instance will be assigned a random port and this random port will be made known to other aspects of your Spring context (such as your `MongoTemplate`) which need to talk to that Mongo instance.